# '１' -> '1', how to convert the left str to the right str

Tags: python

In the following code, `raw` and `want` are both 1, but they are different in computers. I want to convert `raw` to `want`. I have a lot of such strs, how can I convert them in python?

```
raw = '１'  
want = '1'  
print(ord(raw))  # 65297
print(ord(want)) # 49
```

Comment: `ord(raw.strip())` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert unicode representation of number to ascii string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25313773/convert-unicode-representation-of-number-to-ascii-string)

Comment: The following url solve my problem. Thank you. http://www.cnblogs.com/kaituorensheng/p/3554571.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Convert Unicode to ASCII without errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365411/python-convert-unicode-to-ascii-without-errors)

Answer (score 0):

`raw` looks like a unicode '1' (maybe [U+FF11](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff11/index.htm) ?) rather than an ascii '1'.  You could use a dictionary that has the unicode characters as keys and the ascii characters as values.  That might look something like

```
lookup = {'１': '1', ...}
```

And then, when you want to convert the character, you could do something like

```
want = lookup[raw]
```

edit: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25313773/convert-unicode-representation-of-number-to-ascii-string) might be a more robust answer.